# cannot use aggregate function in UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I am getting an error in my code:

> ERROR: cannot use the aggregate function in UPDATE

update pre_project_code:

```
Update ttemp.TMP_KPIR_F_RT_DETAIL a
set pre_project_code = (
                        select tt.old_proj_cde 
                        from ttemp.TMP_KPIR_RT_BASE tt 
                        where tt.contr_id = a.contr_id 
                        and tt.row_number = 1
                       )
WHERE a.renew_type =  '專案異動' or a.row_number = MAX(a.row_number) 
;
```

What is the proper way to write this code?

Comment: please update code format

Comment: Use `a.row_number = (select MAX(row_number) from ttemp.TMP_KPIR_F_RT_DETAIL)`

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what database you are using, but the following should do what you want:

```
Update ttemp.TMP_KPIR_F_RT_DETAIL d
    set pre_project_code = (select b.old_proj_cde 
                            from ttemp.TMP_KPIR_RT_BASE b
                            where b.contr_id = d.contr_id and
                                  b.row_number = 1
                          )
    where d.renew_type =  '專案異動' or
          d.row_number = (select max(d2.row_number) from ttemp.TMP_KPIR_F_RT_DETAIL d2);
```